# Visual Studio Express to Profissional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

If i can ask this here: since there is tons of people that use Visual Studio here i would like to know why i should buy Visual Studio Professional.

I'm using Visual Studio Express.

What i can do/ or what/why it would make my life easy with Pro edition?

And one think that i don't get, i need to renew every year it? 
Or is it lifetime? 
I just renew if i want a new version?

The "plugins" is really better or can i live without it?

The table in Microsoft site don't compare express version with others.

Ty

Comment: VS Express editions does not support plug-ins. Pro+ does for commercial projects, and VS 2013 Community edition supports it for non-commercial projects. VS Express editions only support a single 'target platform' (i.e. Windows Store/Windows phone or Win32 desktiop). Pro+ and Community support targeting multiple platforms. Express editions are also missing other functionality like the VS graphics debugger, etc.

Comment: What happen if i sell a application that i did using VS 2013 Express? There is website for freelancer and others that i can get some money with my program, so i can't use VS 2013 to build my application and sell there?

Comment: Details on the licensing is covered in [this article](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350). VS 2013 Express editions don't have usage restrictions. The limitations for VS 2013 Community are based on your organization, so individuals, teachers, and students basically can do whatever they want with it (INAL, so read the article and EULA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *shouldn't* buy it, at least not if you're a solo developer or small company.

Microsoft now provide their [Visual Studio Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) at no cost, and it's a big step up from the Express editions.

> Visual Studio Community 2013 includes all the great functionality of Visual Studio Professional 2013, designed and optimized for individual developers, students, open source contributors, and small teams.

So, if you're a small shop, that's the one I'd be looking at.

Comment: The table is VS 2010. =( I will look th "Community Edtion"too. ty!

Comment: @Júlio, I _certainly_ wouldn't be using Express 2010 when CE 2013 was exactly the same cost with so much more functionality.

Comment: The Community edition have everything that i need i think! Ty very much! I can't vote up because i don't have rep.